# Trying to disable CSS buttons using ASP hidden value and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the ASP.NET PasswordRecovery method, and have a couple of CSS buttons to submit the form OR cancel the request.

I also grab the users email address to pass along to the successtext value of PasswordRecovery method, set the ASP hiddenvalue to success, and then try to use javascript to disable the buttons based on this value.

The problem is that this hiddenfield value seems to be set to "success" on initial page load, even though when viewing the source of the rendered page shows NO value.

There is probably a better approach to this, but I have tried several different ways, and this is successful up the point that I cant change the view state of the buttons.

> 

```
<script runat="server">
 protected void resetuserpassword_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    e.Message.Subject = "Password Assistance";
    TextBox txtUserName = (TextBox)resetuserpassword.UserNameTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
    string UserEmailID = Membership.GetUser(txtUserName.Text.Trim()).Email;
    resetuserpassword.SuccessText = "Password sent to ";
    resetuserpassword.SuccessText += UserEmailID;
    ValueHiddenField.Value = "Success";
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderArea" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = disableButtons;
    function disableButtons() {
        var element =  document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolderArea_ValueHiddenField');
        if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
                if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolderArea_ValueHiddenField').value = 'Success') {
                    var submitBtnElement = document.querySelector("#submitBtn");
                    var cancelBtnElement = document.querySelector("#cancelBtn");
                    submitBtnElement.style.display = "none";
                    cancelBtnElement.style.display = "none";
                }
        }
    }
    function clickSubmit() {
        document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolderArea_resetuserpassword_UserNameContainerID_SubmitButton").click();
    }
    function clickCancel() {
        window.location.replace("~/Login.aspx");
    }
</script>
    <asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField"    value=""    runat="server"/>
    <asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField"    value=""    runat="server"/>
    <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="resetuserpassword" runat="server" 
        MailDefinition-BodyFileName="~/ResetPasswordEmailTemplate.html" 
        OnSendingMail="resetuserpassword_SendingMail" 
        successtext="Password sent to email address on record."
        Width="300px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" UserNameTitleText="" >
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" />
        <MailDefinition BodyFileName="~/ResetPasswordEmailTemplate.html"></MailDefinition>

        <UserNameTemplate>
            <div><asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" style="display:none;"></asp:Label></div>
            <div style="font: arial, verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 13px;padding-bottom: 5px;font-weight: bold;">Please Enter your Username</div>
            <div><asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" style="width: 180px;"></asp:TextBox></div>
            <div><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
            <div><asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal></div>
            <div style="display: inline;" ><asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1" style="display: none;" /></div> 
        </UserNameTemplate>
    </asp:PasswordRecovery>
        <div>
        <div id="submitBtn" onclick="clickSubmit()">Submit</div>
        <div id="cancelBtn" onclick="clickCancel()">Cancel</div>    
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript if statement is assigning the value 'Success' to the Hidden Field (single equals sign).

```
if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolderArea_ValueHiddenField').value = 'Success') {
...
}
```

Change it to this (double equals sign):

```
if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolderArea_ValueHiddenField').value == 'Success') {
...
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your quick response and keen eyes! ;-)